# Why merging changes between labels for specific file not working?

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-integrate

Assume I have two branches UK_SYS and ASIA_SYS (related but not coming from a simple `copy/integrate` from common ancestor), e.g.

```
[UK_SYS/branches/v1.0]
-----------#-----------#-----------#------>
           @uk-1.0     @uk-1.0.1   @uk-1.0.2

[ASIA_SYS/branches/v1.0]
-----------#-----------#------------------>
           @asia-1.0   @asia-1.0.1
```

There are changes from a specific file (say, foo.txt) from UK_SYS `@uk-1.0` to `@uk-1.0.1` that I want to bring to ASIA_SYS.

In P4V, I am clicking on `foo.txt`, and click `Merge/Integrate`.

I specified `//depot/UK_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt` as `Source file/folders`, and `//depot/Asia_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt` as `Choose target files/folders`.

In `Options` -> `Filter`, I specified `Revisions from/to` and put `From` as `Label, uk-1.0` and `To` as `Label, uk-1.0.1`

However, when I click on Merge or Preview, P4V complains me for `The operation cannot be completed because you cannot limit to and from a label`.  I have no idea why it does not work as it should essentially means ***"Find the changes of `//depot/UK_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt`, between file revision labelled at `@uk-1.0` and file revision labelled at `@uk-1.0.1`.  Then merge the change to `//depot/ASIA_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt`"***.

If I manually find out the file revision of `foo.txt` using the label `@uk-1.0` and `@uk-1.0.1`, and use the revisions as From/To, it seems working (either one will already work), but it is tedious to do the same for a bunch of files.

What is the appropriate way to do such merging? (P4V client I am using is dated 2015 Feb 04, Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2014.3/998867)

Comment: Try it from the command line: p4 integrate //depot/UK_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt@uk-1.0,@uk-1.0.1 //depot/Asia_SYS/branches/v1.0/foo.txt and tell us what happens with that command.